# Cannot convert from Stream<Object> to unknown

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been facing "Cannot convert Stream of Object to unknown" issue while trying to use Map from Lambdas feature.

Code Snippet :

```
List<Address> addresses = infoContactDetails.getAddresses().stream()
                .filter(address -> address.getAddressType().equalsIgnoreCase("Test"))
                .map(address -> address.getAddressType().equalsIgnoreCase("Test")
                        ? null
                        : requestContactDetails.getAtThisAddressSince() ? null : address)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[image: Code screesnshot with error]

[image: My environment variables java home]

[image: My Eclipse Compiler screenshot]

Comment: This compiled just fine for me. Clearly you're doing something wrong. Also, don't map null, you're gunna have a bad time.

Comment: I have mapped null only for making it look simpler for posting it here...which version of JDK are you using ??

Comment: Java 8. What is infoContactDetails? I bet its a List of Object. Man update your jdk 8 btw, update to jdk 8 update 200+. What is requestContactDetails?

Comment: the problem was with the STS version..once i upgraded it it was resolved

Answer (score 1):

This code can be refactored:
This line is redundant as you already do this filter in a line above:

```java
.map(address -> address.getAddressType().equalsIgnoreCase("Test")
```

The same is with `requestContactDetails.getAtThisAddressSince()`, it does not add any value in stream and you know its value before execution. So in the end it can be written like this:

```java
List<Address> addresses = requestContactDetails.getAtThisAddressSince() 
                ? new ArrayList<>() : 
                infoContactDetails.getAddresses().stream()
                .filter(address -> address.getAddressType().equalsIgnoreCase("Test"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```